# how detect MSVCR120.dll is missing with java project

Tags: java, postgresql, netbeans

i'm from indonesian, and i can't speak english

i plan run postgresql binary with my project (With JAVA)
for run server postgresql, i have 2 way :
1. with *.bat file
2. include in my java project

when i run *.bat file, i'm get new windows error message "The program can't start because MSVCR120.dll is missing from your computer....."

but if i run with my java project, i'm not get new windows error message, but server not running..

so, how can i'm show or capture that new windows error message with my java project

or how can i'm check MSVCR120.dll is NOT MISSING

i have source code for run postgresql server :

```
//jika pertama kali dijalankan (folder data tidak ada)
        System.out.println("Firs Time Run");
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(PathAplication.PostgreBinPath + "\\initdb",
                "-U", PG_USER_ROOT, "-A", "trust", "-E", "utf8", "--locale=C");
        Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
        env.put("PGDATA", PathAplication.PostgreDataPath);
        env.put("PGDATABASE", PG_DATABASE_ROOT);
        env.put("PGUSER",PG_USER_ROOT);
        env.put("PGPORT",PG_PORT);

        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
            InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String line;
            boolean started = false;

            while(!started && (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
                started = line.contains("database system is ready to accept connections");
            }            
            RunServer();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FrameRunCommandLine.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

thanks before...

Comment: Show us your batch file and your Java code.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install also x86 version of MSVC redistributable.

I found that even after installing x64 version of MSVC redistributable, the *msvcp120.dll* file was missing in SysWOW64 directory. The issue was solved after installing also x86 version.

**NOte: Even if you're using x64**

Comment: yes, installing msvc redistribution is a solution for my error message. But, how to capture error message from my java project ?

Comment: Correct, and don't try to check if it's missing. Run the redist installer as part of your program installer each and every time.

Comment: problem solved with running this code before running initdb :

process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + PathAplication.AppPath + "\\c_red\\vcredist_x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart");

Comment: @ArdinalSusanto:  Please accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I will also add it is necessary to download the 2013 version
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2013-vc-120

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).